# How to make PHP echo Javascript straight to footer

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that uses PHP to output different blocks of Javascript depending on settings. The code uses a function from an external javascript file (backstretch) that is loaded in the footer.

The theme doesn't load the appropriate images properly unless the backstretch javascript is loaded in the head, and I think it's because the PHP is echo'ing the blocks of code that call the script way before the footer is even loaded (probably wrong assumption).

Is there a way to echo the blocks of Javascript calling Backstretch code straight to the footer (or after backstretch is loaded in the footer)?

The php is echoing the JS like this:

```
  if (x == x) { ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ //code});
    </script>
<?php // more code
```

If I run the javascript in the head (Backstretch javascript) the console sends this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'backstretch' "
```

(jQuery is being loaded in the head by the way)

Thanks guys

Comment: @jimsmith Even using `.ready` isn't enough, if jQuery itself hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: jQuery is being loaded in the head, it;s the external script that isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, theoretically, the position of the script shouldn't matter much for this. The point of jQuery.ready() is that the inside function will not run until the entire DOM has been loaded. "The entire DOM" includes the page's footer, and the Javascript files you're waiting on. However, it's possible that they also wait on the DOM before initializing, and thus jQuery's ready function is called first.

Some of your time-thinking terminology is a little hard to understand though - remember that PHP writes its entire document out to the user a long, long time (computer-wise) before your browser begins parsing any of the HTML.

Comment: Tell me, how exactly would `jQuery.ready()` work if jQuery itself hasn't been loaded yet? It is NOT a bulletproof vest.

Comment: As long as you put it after the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery, it'll run after jquery loads

Comment: If backstretch is loading asyncronously (`document.write('<script.....')`, that's probably the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could just move your code block to the right place, or alternatively try this:

Start your PHP code with `$footer = "";`

Then as you go along you can do `$footer .= "<script>jQuery(document).ready(...)</script>";`

And finally in the right place just `echo $footer;`.

Answer (score 0):

- Edit your functions.php file
- enclose the script in a php function e.g:

  ```
  <?php
  function my_javascript_function_call(){
  <script>
  ....
  </script>
  }
  ?>
  ```
- now add this function

  add_action('wp_footer', 'function my_javascript_function_call');

The javascript will fire in your footer..
happy coding :)